# Chrome treats 'default' result from Notification.requestPermission() as 'denied'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification, permissions

The `Notification.requestPermission()` has 3 possible results: `granted`, `denied` and `default`.

In Chrome you get `default` when the user close the permission dialog using the X instead of explicitly saying `block`. But, if after getting `default` as result, you call `Notification.permission` you get `denied`, making impossible to retry asking permission again in the future.

It this by design? is there a way to make chrome treating differently this two results? Firefox treats this in the right way (you can ask permissions until the user explicitly denied it)

Answer (score 7):

I'll leave this just in case someone is looking for an answer:

When the user had closed the permission dialog for the third time Chrome will automatically set the permission to `denied` (it shows a `automatically blocked` message below on the permission popup from the navbar). So the first three times the user close the dialog you gets `default` as result, but on the third time the permission are set to `denied`.

The way I'm using to work with this logic is:

```
window.Notification.requestPermission().then((result) => {
  if (result === 'denied') {
     // the user has denied permission
     return;
  }

  if (result === 'default') {
    // the user has closed the dialog
    if (window.Notification.permission === 'denied') {
       // the browser has decided to automatically denied permission 
    }
    return;
  }

  // the user has granted permission
});
```

Comment: that's very rare! I was thinking I've implemented something incorrectly

Comment: It could make sense to set it to denied after the third time, but the weird part for me is that `result === 'default'` and not `denied` or something else